# Cell text truncated to about 1390 characters

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I modified the code here - https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3560-excel-send-personalized-email.html

If the text in the cell is long, it is truncated.
[image]

I tried increasing the application time value to 0.20, but that did nothing. It got truncated at the same point.

```vb
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
                         ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
                         ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
                         ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
                         ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
                         ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
                         ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
#End If

Sub SendEMail()
    Dim xEmail As String
    Dim xSubj As String
    Dim xMsg As String
    Dim xURL As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Double
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    On Error Resume Next
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the data range:", "navneesi", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For i = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
    '       Get the email address
        xEmail = xRg.Cells(i, 1)
    '       Message subject
        xSubj = "Validation Assignment"
    '       Compose the message
        xMsg = ""
        xMsg = xMsg & "Validation Assignment: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        xMsg = xMsg & " Order ID: " & xRg.Cells(i, 2).Text & vbCrLf
        xMsg = xMsg & " Marketplace ID: " & xRg.Cells(i, 3).Text & vbCrLf
        xMsg = xMsg & " Order Day: " & xRg.Cells(i, 4).Text & vbCrLf
        xMsg = xMsg & " Seller ID: " & xRg.Cells(i, 5).Text & vbCrLf
        xMsg = xMsg & " Product Code: " & xRg.Cells(i, 6).Text & vbCrLf
        xMsg = xMsg & " Item Name: " & xRg.Cells(i, 7).Text & vbCrLf
        xMsg = xMsg & " Defect Source: " & xRg.Cells(i, 8).Text & vbCrLf
        xMsg = xMsg & " Defect Day: " & xRg.Cells(i, 9).Text & vbCrLf
        xMsg = xMsg & " Defect Text: " & xRg.Cells(i, 10).Text & vbCrLf
        
    '       Replace spaces with %20 (hex)
        xSubj = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xSubj, " ", "%20")
        xMsg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xMsg, " ", "%20")
    '       Replace carriage returns with %0D%0A (hex)
        xMsg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(xMsg, vbCrLf, "%0D%0A")
    '       Create the URL
        xURL = "mailto:" & xEmail & "?subject=" & xSubj & "&body=" & xMsg
    '       Execute the URL (start the email client)
        ShellExecute 0&, vbNullString, xURL, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus
    '       Wait two seconds before sending keystrokes
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Application.SendKeys "%s"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. Edit your question to describe any errors that are no longer invisible.

Comment: @niton Thank you. I removed On Error Resume Next but got no errors. The defect text still got truncated at the same point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix. Instead of using`Cells(i, 5).Text` use `Cells(i, 5).Value`. 
This makes sure the cell content is sent to outlook as it is instead of converting it to text first which gives rise to issues. (The code in the question was also unable to render chinese text.)

Also, instead of executing a mail to url, I included the object library for outlook and declared the object for outlook application and for mail item. Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

Answer (score 0):

Well, 1390 doesn't seem like any kind of restriction that I have ever heard about.  Maybe 255 characters, or a variable-length string of up to approximately 2 billion (2^31) characters, etc.  Can you try doing it this way?

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
    Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .to = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Testfile"
            .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

            For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                    If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                        .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next FileCell

            .Send  'Or use .Display
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

Set OutApp = Nothing
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

NOTE:

Make a list in Sheets("Sheet1") with :

In column A : Names of the people

In column B : E-mail addresses

In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B
and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

Most relevant URL:

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail6.htm

Parent URL:

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm